# yosemite svn 1.6.6 segmentation fault

Tags: c, apache, svn, osx-yosemite, apr

svn stopped working in my Mac after upgrade to Yosemite. I know there is a very similar question with no answer,
[Segmentation fault: 11 in SVN checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021979/segmentation-fault-11-in-svn-checkout), however I've spent pretty much the whole day with this and I'm adding more information on the issue. I'm hoping somebody maybe somebody can help... I'm really stuck. I cannot upgrade svn and I'm planning to go back to Mavericks.

The error I get:

```
svn update
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I was already working with svn from a binary I compiled myself (although not so familiar with C). There was some months ago an update of Xcode that removed the old legacy svn 1.6.

This time with Yosemite, when I've tried to compile it again, I've seen that the os update has modified `apache` and `APR` and the sources do not compile anymore (or at least that's my guess from the error I get):

```
/bin/sh /mnt/netzima/icaria/apps/subversion-1.6.6/libtool --tag=CC --silent --mode=compile gcc -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2  -g -O2   -I/usr/include/apache2 -I./subversion/include -I./subversion -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/local/apr-util/include/apr-1 -I/opt/local/include/neon  -o subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.lo -c subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c
subversion/mod_authz_svn/mod_authz_svn.c:448:9: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union
        ap_log_rerror(file, line, level, 0, r,
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've downloaded and `make install` the following:

- libtool version 2.4.2
- autoconf version 2.69
- automake version 1.14
- apr version 1.3.12
- apr-util version 1.3.12
- apache version 2.2.29

I was hoping that those versions would be compatible with svn 1.6.6, since, as I've mentioned before, my guess was that it is not compatible anymore to the newest versions.

In other to use those packages that I've downloaded, I had to add options to the configure command. For apr-util, I had to configure like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr-util --with-apr=/usr/local/apr
```

As for apache:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-dav --enable-so
```

And finally svn:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --enable-maintainer-mode
```

This way at least svn compiles (I guess that proves it is getting the right versions). But it does not work, I get the same segmentation fault. I've added the /usr/local/... directories to my path just to be sure, although I'd guess svn puts all the library it needs in an accesible directory (I think it is /usr/local/bin, which was already in my path).

I have no idea how to go from here. I've tried to compile with debug to see if I can get a pointer to the segmentation fault, a core dump or something like that, with no success...

Any help would be much appreciated!
And thanks anyway.

EDIT:

Following @indiv advice, this is the output of otool:

```
/usr/local/bin/svn:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 57031.1.35)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1151.16.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 62.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_wc-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_ra-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_diff-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_ra_local-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_repos-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_fs-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_fs_fs-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_fs_util-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.15.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_ra_neon-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_delta-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
/usr/local/apr-util/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.12.0)
/usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.12.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libneon.27.dylib (compatibility version 30.0.0, current version 30.6.0)
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
/opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.2.0)
/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track that it's an incompatible library that's causing the crash.  Run `which svn` to verify you are running the correct SVN.  Add the output of `otool -L /usr/local/bin/svn` to your question to provide additional debug info about the library dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @indiv! I can guess this is the list of libraries it it using. But how to figure out anything else? (Just double-checked which svn)

Comment: There's something [odd about Yosemite's libsasl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663338/is-libsasl2-broken-on-osx-yosemite-missing-sasl-client-done).  I wonder whether that's causing this problem.  I've never built SVN 1.6; does that version support `--without-sasl`?  If so, you can try to reconfigure, rebuild, and re-install with that option.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to continue down this road of debugging your SVN install, you're going to need to rebuild with debug symbols (`CFLAGS=-g`) and run it under `lldb`.  I.e., `lldb svn update` and once in the debugger, enter 'r' for run.  Then 'c' if it breaks with the stop reason of "exec".  You should get a stack trace when it crashes.  I'm afraid that's just about the limit of help I can provide, so good luck.  If it were me, I'd try SVN 1.8.x.  I don't know of any reason why it's necessary to stick with 1.6.x, except I guess for trying to match cmdline svn with some IDE plugin's svn.

Comment: Yes, @indiv, svn 1.6 has sasl as optional dependency. It does support the --withot-sasl. However, the segmentation fault is still there... I've run "otool ..." and the sasl library is not there anymore. I'll try debugging tomorrow (going to bed now, it's been a long day!) Let's see if I get lucky, I'll let you know. (The ./configure command has a --enable-debug option, I'll check if this is adding the CFLAGS you mention). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also download and install the binary from WANDisco:

https://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download/download-certified-wandisco-subversion-binaries?f=subversion/Subversion-Client-1.8.10_10.10.x.pkg

Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the link is for svn 1.8. Which, btw, also comes with xcode. My problem was that I have to stick to 1.6.

Comment: I used a later SVN client (1.7 in my case) with a 1.6 server no problem, just had to `svn upgrade` my repository to use the new client.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked! Thanks @indiv for your help! I was about to give up and revert to Mavericks.

I had to compile neon, version 0.29.0.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/neon --with-ssl
```

Then I recompiled svn:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-mode --without-sasl --with-neon=/usr/local/neon --with-ssl
```

And it works!